# storing data to database with html form in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

form.valid is not working,when i fill the form the data should store in database using html form and also how to upload image,how to define the form in html page,is there anything wrong in my code,below is my models.py,views.py,forms.py is given,i have search many forums but not able to get answer

## models.py

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    Deal_Category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=(('F','Fashion'),
                                                    ('T', 'Travel') ))
    Deal_Title = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    Deal_Redemption = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    Deal_Start = models.DateField()
    Deal_End =models.DateField()
    Deal_Details = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank =True)
    Deal_Location= models.CharField(max_length=50,blank =True)
    Deal_Terms = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank =True)
    #Images = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/image',blank=True)
```

## forms.py

```
class DealForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model= Deal
        fields=('Deal_Category','Deal_Title','Deal_Redemption','Deal_Start','Deal_End','Deal_Details',
                'Deal_Location','Deal_Terms')
```

## views.py

```
def deal_form(request):
    print("Deal")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("user")
        form = DealForm(data=request.POST )
        print("Deal1")
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Deal2")
            form.save(commit=True)
            print("Deal4")
        return render(request, 'advertizer/adver_create_coupon.html')
```

Comment: First, please format your code correctly. Secondly, what do you mean "not working"? What happens? Do you get an error? And finally, where is the rest of that view?

Comment: i am not getting any error but form is not submitting  means data is not storing in the dtabase

Comment: You didn't correct the indentation or post the rest of that view.

Comment: i have uploaded the rest of that view